# Redirect a Rewrite URL Address

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

Adding this to my .htaccess file works to shorten the URL and get rid of the .shtml bit.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule about about.shtml
```

But, the original address http://xxx/about.shtml also still exists. I don't want Google or anyone to see that one, so I tried redirecting it to the rewritten URL:

```
Redirect 301 /about.shtml /about
```

This gives an error on Firefox that it's not working and on Google that it is being redirected too many times. Maybe it's going in some sort of a loop.

I don't want the original file to show up anywhere in the web address (with the.shtml ending), so not sure what else besides a redirect to do.

Thanks!

Comment: I discovered that Google won't index the original file, but the rewrite address. So maybe that resolves this issue.

Comment: Something else I discovered is that with that url rewrite rule any file with the word "about" in it will redirect to the /about.shtml file. It doesn't even matter what folder it's in OR EVEN IF the folder exists. That's right, I deleted the folder I had put another about.HTML (not shtml) file in and if I typed in the old path it would redirect to the /about file, though the address would say x-folder/about.html. I also tried changing the new file to about3.html, and even that redirected. (Cleared the cache and everything.) I think this is a weird bug, but gotta be careful with rewrites!